# CUDA template kernel wrapper

Tags: c++, templates, cuda, wrapper

I started writing a simulation and decided to try use a more objected oriented approach. As such I also decided using a template parameter in the CUDA kernel, which indicates the spatial dimension of the simulation. The problem is, because of the restriction of implementing template functions in the header files, I had to use a complicated approach to keep make the kernel wrapper callable from .cpp source files.

My approach was to overload the wrapper function for 2 and 3 dimensions. I then have a class for wrapper class which deals with initialization and managing the kernel resources. Unfortunately, because of the restriction I mentioned, I have to keep two members for template classes, i.e.

```
struct kernelWrapper{
    KernelWrapper(Simulation<2> *simulation):
        d_(2),
        simulation2d_(simulation)
    {}
    KernelWrapper(Simulation<3> *simulation):
        d_(3),
        simulation3d_(simulation)
    {}
    process(void){ //wrapper function for kernel launching
        switch(d_){
        case 2:
            kernel<2><<<..., ...>>>(...);
            break;
        }
        case 3:
            kernel<3><<<..., ...>>>(...);
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }

    int d_;
    union{
        Simulation<2> *simulation2d_;
        Simulation<3> *simulation3d_;
    };
    union{
        Lattice<2> *lattice2d_d;
        Lattice<3> *lattice3d_d;
    };

};
```

I was thus wondering if you know of a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do, that is, to make a wrapper for a template CUDA kernel.

**UPDATE:** I'd like to add one more solution I've found out after making the above post. As indicated by the [C++ faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/templates.html) (points 13-15) one can put the template implementation in a source file and explicitly instantiate the templates that are needed, i.e. in my case for 2 and 3 dimensions. Using C++11, one can take this a step further and introduce the keyword `extern` in the template definition to save some compiling/linking time, also explained [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is, because of the restriction of implementing template
>   functions in the header files, I had to use a complicated approach to
>   keep make the kernel wrapper callable from .cpp source files.

It is legal to write a template declared code in .cpp

Whether `kernelWrapper` is in .hpp or .cpp you should have a code that looks like

```
template<int d_>
struct kernelWrapper
{
    KernelWrapper(Simulation<d_> *simulation) : simulation_(simulation)
    {}

    process(void)
    {
            kernel<d_><<<..., ...>>>(...);
    }

    Simulation<d_>* simulation_;
    Lattice<d_>*    lattice2d_;
};
```

Also avoid using switch/case to select a kernel, use something like:

```
int const max_dimension = 4;

template<int static_dimension>
void select_kernel(int dynamic_dimension)
{
    if(dynamic_dimension == static_dimension)
    {
        call_kernel<static_dimension>();
    }
    select_kernel<static_dimension+1>(dynamic_dimension);
}

template<>
void select_kernel<max_dimension>(int dynamic_dimension)
{
    // error message
}

void select_kernel(int dynamic_dimension)
{
    select_kernel<1>(dynamic_dimension);
}
```

If such selection is frequent, it makes sens to not using templates.

Comment: Excuse if I didn't understand your answer correctly. Of course, the code you posted would be the most straightforward, but you'd have to include the kernel implementation too. Then I'd have to use a .cu extension for the file that includes the KernelWrapper and compile it with nvcc. My point is to make the KernelWrapper callable from a plain .cpp source file.

Comment: Now I better understand your issue. The kernel execution configuration syntax <<<a,b,c,d>>> isn't recognized by a cpp compiler. You should use the non-template version of `select_kernel` to call the kernel in cpp compiled code and define `select_kernel` in the nvcc compiled portion.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. The kernel launching is very frequent, I will take a look how much different the performance is with the `select_kernel` version.

Comment: If kernel calls are frequent with changing dimension then removing the template integer and passing `d_` through pcie is the simplest solution (won't really affect performance). switch/case is ugly, can affect performance due to branching and in your case you're *duplicating* code (evil)

Comment: The calls are frequent but the dimension doesn't change through the run. Wouldn't switch/case be faster? Your code still needs to evaluate at least one (if you change 1 to 2 in the non-templated version) if statement each time it is called.

Comment: the switch/case is faster in that case. make sure to use switch/case in `select_kernel` because your original code has duplication

Comment: a.lasram, I marked your answer as correct, but I think I'll use explicit instantiation of the templates instead.